# Create a package that has three public procedures named proc 1, etc

Tags: oracle, plsql

I should solve the following problem:

> Create a package called hellofrom that contains three public procedures named proc_1, proc_2 and proc_3. Each of these procedures should use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE() to display the message “Hello from Proc x” where “x” is 1 or 2 or 3, as appropriate.
>
> Also, proc_1 should call proc_2 and proc_2 should call proc_3, so you need to include a reference to proc_2 from proc_1, and a reference to proc_3 from proc_2.

I wrote the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY hellofrom IS
   PROCEDURE proc_1  ---public procedure
     (p_hello_1  IN VARCHAR2)
   IS   v_sec_hello   VARCHAR2;   --LOCAL VARIABLE
   BEGIN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(proc_1: 'Hello from Proc 1');
   END hello_1;

   PROCEDURE proc_2  ---public procedure
       (p_hello_2   IN VARCHAR2)
   IS    v_thd_hello   VARCHAR2;   --LOCAL VARIABLE 
   BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(proc_2: 'Hello from Proc 2');
   END hello_2;

   PROCEDURE proc_3    ---public procedure
        (p_hello_3    IN  VARCHAR2)
   IS      v_sec_hello        --LOCAL VARIABLE
   BEGIN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(proc_3: 'Hello from Proc_3');
   END hello_3;
```

But when I execute it I get an error:

```
Error at line 23: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" 
    when expecting one of the following:

    begin function pragma procedure
```

Why do I get this error and how can I resolve it?
for 
Now I made a code for this part of question: Also, proc_1 should call proc_2 and proc_2 should call proc_3, so you need to include a reference to proc_2 from proc_1, and a reference to proc_3 from proc_2. This is what I have:

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY hellofrom IS
  FUNCTION  call_proc  --private function
   (p_proc_1    VARCHAR2,
    p_proc_2    VARCHAR2,
    p_proc_3    VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   BEGIN
    IF p_proc_1 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello from Proc_2');
    ELSEIF p_proc_2 THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello from Proc_3');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello');
 END IF;
END call_proc;
   PROCEDURE proc_1
   IS
   BEGIN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello from Proc 1');
   END proc_1;

```
PROCEDURE proc_2
IS
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello from Proc 2');
END proc_2;

PROCEDURE  proc_3
IS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello from Proc 3');
END proc_3;
```

END hellofrom;

And this is what is coming back.
Error at line 33: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

begin function pragma procedure

1. CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY hellofrom IS
2. FUNCTION  call_proc  --private function
3. (p_proc_1    VARCHAR2,
4. p_proc_2    VARCHAR2,
5. p_proc_3    VARCHAR2)

I thought I put a function in. Not sure what the mistake is.

Comment: Do your homework yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Create a package called hellofrom that contains three public procedures named proc_1, proc_2 and proc_3. Each of these procedures should use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE() to display the message “Hello from Proc x” where “x” is 1 or 2 or 3, as appropriate

Comment: Actually I got a different wrror message that indicates that no blank is allowed in line 6 after`proc_1:`. I use SQL Worksheett in livesql.oracle.com

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any arguments to the procedure and you aren't using the local variables so they can be removed. You just have a package body and no specification - you need one. The name of the procedure after the `END` statements does not match the name in the signature. You need to correct the syntax errors in the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` statements.

You also need to call `proc_2` from `proc_1` and `proc_3` from `proc_2` ... but its your homework so you can complete that.

Just remember that when you submit it you need to add an attribution linking back to the answer you used (as required by the license [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)).

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE hellofrom IS
   PROCEDURE proc_1;
   PROCEDURE proc_2;
   PROCEDURE proc_3;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY hellofrom IS
   PROCEDURE proc_1
   IS
   BEGIN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello from Proc 1');
   END proc_1;

   PROCEDURE proc_2
   IS
   BEGIN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello from Proc 2');
   END proc_2;

   PROCEDURE proc_3
   IS
   BEGIN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello from Proc_3');
   END proc_3;
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT object_name, status FROM USER_OBJECTS
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d5c374/2/0)**:

```
| OBJECT_NAME | STATUS |
|-------------|--------|
|   HELLOFROM |  VALID |
|   HELLOFROM |  VALID |
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the END line for the package body:

```
END hellofrom;
```

but it still won't compile because each of your calls to `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` are incorrect. Instead of

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(proc_1: 'Hello from Proc 1');
```

they should read

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello from Proc 1');
```

Fix all three of them and you should be on your way.

Best of luck.